# If the * of morphisms (poly. maps) are equal, are the morphisms equal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $t,s:X\rightarrow Y$ be polynomial maps between affine varieties and $t_*,s_*:k[Y]\rightarrow k[x]$ be their images under the representable contravariant functor. We've learnt that for any $\tau:k[Y]\rightarrow k[x]$ there exists a $t:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $t_*=\tau$. ('* is a surjective functor', is it proper to say that?). My question is then, is * also injective, meaning that if $t_*=s_*$ than t=s?

(Note that my teacher doesn't use category theoretic language, I project my little category theory knowledge upon the algebraic geometry we learn).

Edit: I think  that it is, because if $t(x_1,..x_n)=(f_1(x),..f_m(x)), s(x)=(g_1(x),..g_m(x))$ and we look at $y_i$ as polynomial maps, then
$$ f_i=y_i(t(x))=t_*(y_i)=s_*(y_i)=y_i(s(x))=g_i$$
Am I correct?

Comment: Dear Idan, I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean with $\tau=t_\ast$? One is a functor, while the other is a morphism. If you are asking whether, it is the case that if the two functors $t_\ast$ and $s_\ast$ are the same on all affine varieties, they are isomorphic functors? Then, it is true only if the isomorphism is natural.

Comment: For $t:X\rightarrow Y$, then $t_*:k[Y]\rightarrow k[x] : t_*(f(x))=f(t(x))$, so $t_*$ is a morphism  between rings as is $\tau$, and * is the functor. But as I said, we never used words like functor in the lecture so I might be wrong about my definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure. Even more is true (and well known): The coordinate ring gives an (anti)equivalence of categories between affine varieties and finitely generated $k$-domains.

What you call "surjective functor" is called "full functor", and what you call "injective functor" is called "faithful functor". If both are satisfies, one calls this a "fully faithful functor".

Comment: Great! is there a consequence for the fact that there is a fully faithful functor between those (or any two) categories?

Comment: Yes, this is how elementary algebraic geometry works ...